# Prettier not being able to format a Typescript class: privatizing a parameter within the super() throws error

Tags: typescript, prettier

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilitiesService {
  constructor(
    @OgmaLogger(UtilitiesService)
    private readonly logger: OgmaService,
    @Inject('SRV:BOT[BASE]') private readonly base: BaseService,
    @Inject('SRV:BOT[VALIDATION]')
    private readonly validation: ValidationService,
    private readonly client: Client,
    private readonly config: ConfigService,
  ) {}
}
```

throws SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word 'private'. (12:4) when formatting.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it... somehow. Not sure how, but I've fixed it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).